# How to make the view background transparent only if the view is used inside an iOS 7 popover?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uipopovercontroller

The [iOS 7 HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) says:

> (By default, table views, navigation bars, and toolbars in a popover
>   use a transparent background to let the popover’s blurring show
>   through.)

What is the recommended way to replicate this behavior of the table view (white background on iOS 6 and/or when not in a popover, transparent when in an iOS 7 popover) for my custom views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple just set the UITableView background for iOS 6 to white and for iOS 7 make it clear

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else if (isPresentedWithPopOver) {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

Comment: The problem is, when not in a popover it needs to be white on iOS 7, too.

Comment: In that case you have to manage one more variable when you are presenting UITableView in popover

Comment: UITableView does this automatically. But how does Apple's table view know about the content of its internal equivalent to isPresentedWithPopOver without being explicitly told? I'd like to do it for my custom view the same way.

Comment: when you present table into a popover then you can define and set this kinda variable to modify behaviour because tableView never know from where its presenting.

Comment: The UITableView somehow knows from where it is presenting. And I want to find out how the magic works.

Comment: Can you explain "somehow"?